# How do I get the elementView size of UML classes using JointJS?

Tags: jointjs

I'm implementing the class diagram where the users can change the class' name, attributes and methods. I'm having trouble with resizing the class rectangle width depending on name, attribute or method length. These can overflow and go outside the rectangle, and I just can't find a method to get the correct size.

I also have added an element tool to the elementView, and set its x and y to "100%". According to documentation: "Use percentage strings (e.g. '40%') to position the button relatively to the element width/height." but I guess this isn't the model's size, as I typed JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON()) and got the following.

[JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJQVI.png)

The size is the default value I set (260x100).

I checked the size of the attribute using DevTools:

[Size of attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9e0j.png)

The gray button detects the width number I need (330), so I guess that the x in element tools is the elementView's width. I looked at the documentation and can't find any method like .size() or .getSize() for the elementView. I need to resize the rectangle to the size of Max(name length, attribute length, method length) + some aditional space to not look cramped up. I have seen some solutions like "Use [number of letters] * [some constant]" but that is no good as typing 5 "W"s doesn't take the same space as typing 5 "i"s.

So how do I get the width of the whole element (in my case 330 from text length + the three pixels from the left border of the rectangle to the first text letter)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after searching through several Google Groups chats I found some pieces of code that helped me.

For getting the width I needed, I used `elementView.getBBox().width`.

Where I didn't have the element view right at hand, I at least had the model ID, and so I used `paper.findViewByModel(modelId)` to get the element view.